# I'm out of space on /var. How do I resize and move a UFS partition?

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, ufs

I was upgrading FreeBSD packages as part of a minor version upgrade and I ran out of space on `/var/cache/pkg`. Now I need to

- shrink `/usr`
- move `/usr` and `/tmp`
- grow `/var`

Is this possible with FreeBSD? If I've understood what I've read so far, I *should* be able to shrink `/usr` with `growfs -s <smallersize> /dev/ada0p6` but I have no idea how to relocate the partitions. (It would be easy with gparted, but the manual says gparted can't modify UFS partitions.)

Can anyone give me a step-by-step to do this, or do I need to bite the bullet and do a wipe-and-reinstall? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe would be useful if you post `gpart show -l`: if `/usr` and `/var` aren't side-by-side you can't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pracitcal use I would clearly recommend to just back up the data, recreate the partitions and restore. This will be much faster.

[growfs(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=growfs&sektion=8) has had the ability to resize a mounted file system since FreeBSD 10.0.

From the [Handbook](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/disks/#disks-growing) we learn that the partitions can only be resized into contiguous free space. This is why a commenter (@uzsolt) asked for the output of `gpart show -l`.

So you can do all the things you want easily except relocate the partition. I know of no tool which does this automatically for you. And this would be the problem if your space is not contiguous. You will then need to create a new partition and move the data there. To be able to do that you need to have enough free space and if space is a problem this becomes painful.

If your system is in a VM then you can probably easily attach more space. If this is a physical system then I would attach a USB disk and do a backup/restore rather than a full reinstall. Or maybe it was what you were implying.

Dumping and restoring a slice (s1d) is not too scary:

```
dump -0Laf - /dev/ada0s1d  | restore -rf -
```

You can see all the steps to go trough in the article [Resize Existing FreeBSD Root Partition or Slice Safely Without Re-Installing or Rebooting](http://www.unibia.com/unibianet/freebsd/resize-existing-freebsd-root-partition-or-slice-safely-without-re-installing-or-rebooting)

And a final little note: You have a couple of other options to solve your current problem with the minor upgrade. You could link to another location for `var/cache/pkg` - or even better - set `PKG_CACHEDIR` in [pkg.conf(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg.conf&sektion=5)

Comment: Changing `PKG_CACHEDIR` via `setenv` solved my problem. I've revised my question title slightly to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to omit the -u ( update ) flag?

Comment: Absolutely. No reason to create `/etc/dumpdates` in this case (I'll update)